# how to add timthumb rewrite after theme set up

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming

here is my htaccess rewrite rule for my theme's timthumb script.

```
RewriteRule ^pics/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/(.*)$ wp-content/themes/mt_movie/crop.php?src=$5&h=$1&w=$2&q=$3&zc=$4 [L]
```

I found a text about rewrite rules, on wp codes docs pages. 
But i don't know what should i do / or how can i use my RewriteRule via this functions.

Here is the doc link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Actually i want to add this rule after when my theme activated on my customer's web site?

Could anyone help me about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Apache rewrite rule.  It should go in the .htaccess file in the wordpress directory on your server, assuming that your web server is apache.

Comment: i know. there isnt no way for this huh ?

Comment: Not sure what your question is.  There IS a way for it.  You just paste that RewriteRule into the .htaccess file which is in the root folder of your wordpress install.

Comment: yeah i do it normally but i want to update .htaccess file or rewrite rule programatically when the costumer activate my theme.